# aws waiting time of requests are very long

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an aws elastic beanstalk environment application. 
My server is in java with tomcat.
I minified my js and css.
Still when I look in the network tab in chrome I see that the waiting time for each request is very long. The files are not so big.

My ec2 instance is of type t1.micro.

I'm not sure how to handle this... please help.

**UPDATE:**

When I run the website locally (with localhost) everything is great, the problem is only remotely. So I guess that the problem is not in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different instance type (e.g., t2.micro).

The t1.micro instances have very limited performance. See [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html):

> T1 Micro instances (t1.micro) provide a small amount of consistent CPU resources and allow you to increase CPU capacity in short bursts when additional cycles are available. They are well suited for lower throughput applications and websites that require additional compute cycles periodically.

If the performance is not meeting your needs, then you should try a different instance type. This would help you determine if the perceived bad performance is due to the t1.micro instance type or due to an implementation problem in your application that should be optimized.

The [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html) also contain this note:

> The t1.micro is a previous generation instance and it has been replaced by the t2.micro, which has a much better performance profile. We recommend using the t2.micro instance type instead of the t1.micro.

Comment: Tried to create t2.micro and didn't help a lot. Also my code does nothing when requesting static content and still it takes a lot (~400ms-1.5s)

Comment: @julius_am So, try a real instance type. The "T" instance types seem to be useless for anything other than a placeholder (need an instance that will eventually answer, but performance doesn't matter). Either live with the poor performance, or pay a bit more for a more capable instance type.

Comment: Before I upgrade my instance I'd like to make sure all my tomcat configurations and other stuff are ok. But I'm not sure what I should check...

Comment: @Rob: I wouldn't call the "t2" famility "not real" - they are definitely production grade instances (if that's what you mean by "real"/"not real"; otherwise, please specify). They are just "different" - lots of people have a hard time properly designing an architecture to fully leverage t2 instances, but they are definitely just as real as any other, possibly larger, instance type!